# Is starting OTP application manually required on test suit

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp

I use, for example, `HTTPotion`.

It is listed like this in `mix.exs`:

```
  def application do
    [ applications: [:httpotion]
  end
```

Do I need to provide `HTTPotion.start()` in test_helper or in setup macro?

Sometimes my tests fail, because HTTPotion didn't start, so I add this line in helper. However, after sometime it can fail again, so I need to remove it, compile, and add it again, compile again and it works again.

I can't understand does the problem lies it this field or it is something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No, you don't.

When you want to run HTTPotion in iex, every time before that you have to use this sentence `HTTPotion.start`, but that's the whole point of using mix- it handles starting applications for you in the background.

Please read [this](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/supervisor-and-application.html) note, espesially the sentence:

> Mix normally starts the whole hierarchy of applications defined in our project’s mix.exs file and it does the same for all dependencies if they depend on other applications.

.